# Tool for detecting memory corruption in a mixed-mode application

Tags: c#, memory, c++-cli, mixed-mode

Can anyone recommend a free or commercial tool that detects memory corruption (NOT memory leak) in a C# 4.0 application that calls unmanaged C++ libraries via a C++/CLI bridge? We are using [Redgate Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/dotnet-developer-bundle/) but it is not designed to help with the unmanaged code (this is where the memory corruption occurs). Thanks.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20028

Comment: @Hans Passant: interesting tool, but it is solely for unmanaged code. I think the problem manifests itself only when the entire mixed-mode application is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used it but according to what others on SO wrote this http://memprofiler.com/ is a managed profiler providing information on native memory too (in one tool)...

Comment: SciTech's profiler is an excellent tool, but I'm not aware that it detects memory corruption.